# Unable to fetch the most up-to-date value from Trigger

Tags: trigger, integration, after-trigger

I've encountered an issue with retrieving the latest BillingLatitude value through a trigger. It consistently retrieves the old value in an 'After Update' Trigger, even when the entire address is modified on the Account. I suspect this is due to the  fact that after the Account is updated, the Data Integration Rule should ideally fire to update the geocode values. Despite having 'Bypass triggers' set to false on the Data Integration Rule, I'm still unable to fetch the most up-to-date value within the Trigger.

If anyone has insights or knows of a workaround for this situation, I'd greatly appreciate your assistance.

Comment: As a basic sanity check, are you using data from `trigger.old` or `trigger.oldMap` instead of `trigger.new` or `trigger.newMap`?

Comment: I have tried all 4 of the above with debugs. Entry Criteria is After update on Account. Condition being New value on BillingLatitude != old Value on BillingLatitude. Problem is that New value & OldValue is same always the same, even after a change in the record.